# SQL server CE Update Not working with nvarchar as PK

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

Table (Barcodes) Structure:

```
Barcode - nvarchar(30) Unique, PK   
ProductID - bigint
```

If I run the update:
    Update Barcodes SET ProductID = 1000 WHERE ProductID = 2
Then this works. So I know I am looking at the right DB and the update command should work.

But 
    Update Barcodes SET ProductID = 1000 WHERE Barcode = '123456789'
Does not work, no error but no change to the DB.

I'm pulling my hair out, but that's not helping either.

Is it an issue with SQLCE?

If anyone can help that would be great!
Thanks

Comment: Does the appropriate record exist, try a Select where barcode = '123456789' . It looks like mostly, there isnt a matching record in the table to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that Barcode where ProductId = 1000 does not have whitespaces...

Comment: Is there a way I can do this in the query? i.e. trim([productID]) = 1000

Comment: So looking in the database, the field has no white space (selected the field and only the code was highlighted, nothing behind).
However I then tried rtrim([productID])=1000 and it did the update.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do `WHERE Barcode LIKE '%123456789%'` if it has white spaces before and after `'123456789'`